# In loop, check for 6/16/26/36, etc?

Tags: php

If you have a simple counter loop, how do you detect special patterns, for example, every 10 increments but at 6/16/26/36. $i needs to start at 0 too.
The only approach I can think of is this one, but obviously it doesn't work for large loops:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 1000; $i++) { 
    // if ( $i == 6 || $i == 16 || $i == 26...... etc ) { do something }

}
```

Comment: `if (($i % 10) == 6)`

Comment: Of course, that works perfectly! Can you submit as answer to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's not going to be one single answer for all types of patterns, but so long as there *is* a pattern, you can figure it out:

```
for ($i=0; $i<1000; $i++) {
    if (($i-6)%10 == 0) {
        // every time $i minus 6 is evenly divisible by 10
    }
}
```